# Данные SharedPreferences не получается передать из Activity в Repository для подстановки в аргумент метода из Dao

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-shared-preferences, android-room

У мне в room-базе содержится словарь, слова поделены на 4 категории (0, 1, 2 и 3) - указаны в ссот поле таблицы.
с помощью SwitchButton в MenuActivity я добавляю/убираю категории (сохраняются в sharedPreferences), которые должны быть добавлены при запуске WorkActivity.
При запуске WorkActivity вызывается метод get4words() из Dao, где аргументом является List из цифр, в него-то и добавляются
категории, сохраненные в sharedPreferences при переключении SwitchButton в MenuActivity.
Проблема что они не добавляются. Не могу найти ошибку. Где она может быть и как исправить?

In Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE category IN(:filterCategory) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4")
    Single<List<Word>> get4words(List<Integer> filterCategory);
```

In Repository:

```
public class WordRepository {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> FILTERCATEGORY;
    private WordDao mWordDao;
    private Single<List<Word>> m4words;
    WordRepository(Application application) {
        WordDatabase db = WordDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mWordDao = db.WordDao();
        FILTERCATEGORY = new ArrayList<>();
        m4words = mWordDao.get4words(FILTERCATEGORY);}
    Single<List<Word>> get4words() {
        return m4words;
    }
    public void addCategory(int category) {
        FILTERCATEGORY.add(category);
    }
```

In ViewModel:

```
private WordRepository mRepository;
// declaring variables
    public WordViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    mRepository = new WordRepository(application);
    //declaring}
public void addCategory(int category) {mRepository.addCategory(category);}
```

In MenuActivity:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
    switch1.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Category0", true));
    switch2.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Category1", true));
    switch3.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Category2", true));
    switch4.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Category3", true));

    switch1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (switch1.isChecked()) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Category3", true);
            editor.apply();
            switch1.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Category3", false);
            editor.apply();
            switch1.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    //other categories n methods
```

In WorkActivity:

```
private WordViewModel wordViewModel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean category0 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Category0", true);
        boolean category1 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Category1", true);
        boolean category2 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Category2", true);
        boolean category3 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Category3", true);
        if (category1 == true) {
            wordViewModel.addCategory(1);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: verbs added: called");
        }
        //other categories
        //other methods
```

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно вас понимаю, вы берете значения методом mWordDao.get4words(FILTERCATEGORY) при создании объекта WordRepository, однако добавляете уже после в методе addCategory.
То есть берете значения когда список еще пустой.

Comment: Это всмысле во Repository? А как правильно переписать?